# Корпус стражей исламской революции - в кавычках?

Tags: пунктуация

Корпус стражей исламской революции (КСИР) - надо закавычивать и нужно ли *исламской* писать с прописной? Исламская революция - надо писать как Великая французская революция (то есть первое слово с прописной)?

Корпус Стражей Исламской революции  — элитное иранское военно-политическое формирование. Так пишет Википедия.

Вроде бы если это формирование, или по-другому *корпус*, то это не условное название организации и кавычки не нужны.

Answer (score 2):

При неустоявшемся написании названия невемо чего возможны варианты. Я бы спокойно закавычила, потому что разрешено всё, что не запрещено.

Какие они мне Стражи? С прописной-то?

С Великой французской не стоит и сравнивать: великая - одна, а исламских,  э-э-э... ну, в общем, таскать вам, не перетаскать (с).

С прописной только первое слово, потому что дороже второго, или см. [ПРАВИЛА УПОТРЕБЛЕНИЯ ПРОПИСНЫХ И СТРОЧНЫХ БУКВ  »»   Названия исторических эпох и событий, календарных периодов и праздников, общественных мероприятий...](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=7128)

Пока это безобразие не будет зафиксировано словарями и/или справочниками, будем следовать правилу: без кавычек, первое слово - с прописной, как у Вас в первой строке.